# Mongodb Sharding on heterogeneous cluster with replica set

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a capacity planning to deploy mongoDB with sharding and replication. But the servers are not of the same capacity.

I am not able to find proper references to validate whether it is a right choice to go with heterogeneous cluster.

I am planning for 3 shards. 2 Machines of same capacity whereas the third one is of lower capacity. And, for replica set I have same infrastructure. 2 Machines of same capacity and 1 with lower capacity.  Someone please advise or provide reference for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have your machine specs be the same in any replica set or sharded cluster just to make your life easier. Is it solely capacity that is lower? If its memory and CPU that are also lower you may run into issues where by under powered secondary members of the set are unable to keep up with the load of the higher specced primary.

You can sign up to MongoDB Cloud Manager to help you track your disk usage and set alerts on metrics that will warn you if you are running our of capacity.

You might want to consider using tag-aware sharding to pin certain users to the less powerful nodes so they dont get overwhelmed.